# Height of BST +1 more than expected

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I made a function which determines the height of BST, but when the height of the tree is e.g. 2, the result that appears for me is 3, etc. I don't know what I should change in my code. If you need whole code to be able to answer me, tell me, so I'll copy it.

```
def maxDepth(self, node):
    if node is None:
        return 0

    else:

        # Compute the depth of each subtree
        lDepth = self.maxDepth(node.left)
        rDepth = self.maxDepth(node.right)

        # Use the larger one
        if (lDepth > rDepth):
            return lDepth + 1
        else:
            return rDepth + 1
```

Comment: If I have this kind of tree, I'd expect to have height=2 instead of 3.
`tree.BSTinsert(Node(5))
tree.BSTinsert(Node(3))
tree.BSTinsert(Node(8))
tree.BSTinsert(Node(2))
tree.BSTinsert(Node(7))
tree.BSTinsert(Node(9))
`

Comment: Instead of `return 0` just do `return -1` and you'll get desired height.

Comment: @sunny Please read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67545199/941531) (read it fully) I showed there two proofs (one from Wikipedia and one from famous book) that height should be edge-based meaning height of single-node `5` should have height `0` and empty tree `None`-tree should have height `-1`. So your code above is incorrect by +1 and should be corrected as you requested in your question. My answer does this correction of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `return 0` just do `return -1` and you'll get desired height smaller by 1. Corrected code is below:

```
def maxDepth(self, node):
    if node is None:
        return -1
    else:
        # Compute the depth of each subtree
        lDepth = self.maxDepth(node.left)
        rDepth = self.maxDepth(node.right)

        # Use the larger one
        if (lDepth > rDepth):
            return lDepth + 1
        else:
            return rDepth + 1
```

Also you can use built-in [max()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function to make your code shorter:

```
def maxDepth(self, node):
    if node is None:
        return -1
    return max(self.maxDepth(node.left), self.maxDepth(node.right)) + 1
```

---

**Note**: OP is correct, height should be edge-based, i.e. tree with one node `5` should have height of 0. And empty tree (None-tree) has height -1. There are two proofs of this:

One proof in Wikipedia [Tree Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminology) says that height is edge based and `Conventionally, an empty tree (tree with no nodes, if such are allowed) has height −1.`

And another proof in famous book `Cormen T.H. - Introduction to Algorithms`:

[image]

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I think it is up to definition, depends how OP wants. For example tree having one node for example value `"5"` should have height 0 by OP definition. And `None`-tree is smaller than this `"5"` so at least to me it seems to be logical that it should have smaller height than `"5"` meaning it should have -1. For me seems unlogical that two trees `"5"` and `None` should both have height of 0. But anyway it is up to definition. If OP says I will correct my code so that None-tree will have height of 0.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I just read Wiki [Article about Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminology) and it says `Conventionally, an empty tree (tree with no nodes, if such are allowed) has height −1.` So I think you're incorrect if you downvoted (maybe not you, sorry) my answer because of returning -1 for None-tree.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut To the end of my answer I added just now also famous Cormen's book photo which shows that height is edge-based.